# Count number of files, folders and subfolders using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a list of all the folders in a particular location on my local drive. The code below counts the number of files. How would I modify it so that the count includes files and folders NOT just files

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "root=%cd%"

set "folder="
for %%r in ("%root%") do (
    set "rootDrive=%%~dr\" 
    if not defined rootDrive set "rootDrive=\\"
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
        dir /s /a "%%~fr.\*" 2^>nul ^| findstr /r /c:"^  " /c:"^ .*\\."
    ') do for /f "tokens=1,* delims=\" %%b in ("%%~a") do if not "%%c"=="" (
        set "folder=%%c"
    ) else if defined folder (
        for /f %%d in ("%%~a") do (
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            echo(!rootDrive!!folder! : %%d
            endlocal
        )
        set "folder="
    )
) >> output.txt
```

Comment: Do you want the count of files and folders, or the actual list? Also please specify what you mean by all files and folders, what about hidden files etc?

Comment: if it is just count of files and folders of the entire tree,, then simply try this from cmdline. `for /f %a in ('dir /s /a /b ^| find /v /c ""') do set cnt=%a` and see the result.

Answer (score 0):

You could give this a try, *it is untested and may take some time on a large directory structure*:

```bat
@(For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('Dir/W/A-L 2^>Nul')Do @Set/A_f=_d,_d=%%A 2>Nul
    Set/A_d-=2&Call Set/P"=%CD% : %%_f%% : %%_d%%"<Nul&Echo(
    For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('Dir/B/S/AD-L 2^>Nul')Do @(
        For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%B In ('Dir/W/A-L "%%A" 2^>Nul'
        )Do @Set/A_f=_d,_d=%%B 2>Nul
        Set/A_d-=2&Call Set/P"=%%A : %%_f%% : %%_d%%"<Nul&Echo())>"output.txt"
```

*Note: As this is designed to run from the current directory, the `output.txt` file will be counted in its own ouptut.*

**[Edit /]**

I suppose you could do the same thing using delayed expansion too, which may speed up the process by a fraction. Here's a modification of the above which uses delayed expansion and just for the sake of it, produces the output in a 'relative' format too:

```bat
@(For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('Dir/W/A-L 2^>Nul')Do @Set/A_f=_d,_d=%%A 2>Nul
Set/A_d-=2&SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion&Echo(\ : !_f! : !_d!&EndLocal
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('Dir/B/S/AD-L 2^>Nul')Do @(
    For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%B In ('Dir/W/A-L "%%A" 2^>Nul'
    )Do @Set/A_f=_d,_d=%%B 2>Nul
    Set/A_d-=2&Set "_a=%%A"&SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Echo(!_a:%__CD__%=\! : !_f! : !_d!&EndLocal))>"output.txt"
```